# Не работает скрипт PHP на сервере Centos8, вечное ожидание выполнения

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код такой, все его ошибки через консоль я отладил.Так же не работают многие команды типа php -d dispalay_errors=1

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q

<?php

require (‘phpagi.php’);

$agi = new AGI();

$recname = strval($agi->request[‘uniqueid’]);

$url = ‘https://api.wit.ai/speech?v=20160526&access_token=API_wit_ai’;

$data = file_get_contents(‘/tmp/’.$recname.’.wav’);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = ‘X-Requested-With: JSONHttpRequest’;
$headers[] = ‘Content-Type: audio/wav’;
$resource = curl_init();

curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);

$result= curl_exec($resource);
$result= json_decode($result);

curl_close($resource);

$result = serialize($result);

preg_match_all(‘/[а-я А-Я]+/u’,$result,$matches);
```

Comment: в чем вопрос (проблема)?

Comment: ошибки curl можно получить функцией https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: Проблема в том что скрипт при выполнении не завершается

Comment: php -d dispalay_errors=1 почему не заканчивает выполнение можете объяснить или я чего то не понимаю, ведь это же просто

Comment: опции dispalay_errors в php нет, есть display_errors, но она не останавливает работу скрипта, а отвечает за вывод ошибок, уровень этих ошибок устанавливается опцией error_reporting

Comment: если скрипт подвисает на получении ответа на запрос к api.wit.ai, то вы можете установить таймаут соединения в опции curl CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT и тогда если API не ответит в течение установленного таймаута, то соединение разорвется и скрипт завершится